# Send email as distribution group address with Redemption - which works in Outlook manually

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I want to send an email 'from' my distribution group. I set all the 'SentOnBehalfOf' properties accordingly and it does go into the correct store's sent items folder and shows as sent from the DG. But I get undeliverable in the default Outlook Inbox.

It sounds like 'send as' permissions, but manually sending an email by typing in the DG address in the 'from' box DOES work.

Are there other Redemption properties I need to use?

Comment: Have you tried to compare bad (sent with Redemption) and good (sent through Outlook) messages using OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?

Comment: Haven't used OutlookSpy but will try that thanks.

Comment: OK, I have several accounts, with emails with different domains. In outlook I can create new mail, set 'other' from address, set the 'send using' and it is all fine. But doing same programmatically says 'send rights issue'. I have located the correct store, create new mail using the folderoutbox.items of that store,  set the newmail.account property, set the 'sender' and 'sentonbehalfof' properties.

Comment: Well it looks like setting the 'SentOnBehalfOf' properties just doesn't work with varying domains. Best I can achieve is receiving a mail as though from the individual, but setting the ReplyRecipient so any reply is addressed back to 'admin' or whatever.

Comment: So what is different between the good and the bad messages?